# realtek HD audio manager - headphones muted on startup

Tags: windows-7, laptop, audio, speakers

I have a dell Inspiron 1121 with Realtek HD audio manager installed on Windows 7. Audio from internal speakers works fine on startup, but when I have headphones plugged in while the computer is off, neither internal speakers or headphones have sound on startup until I re-plug them in. Then they work fine.

RHDAM shows that headphones are plugged in on startup, but no sound. The simple solution is to unplug and then re-plug my headphones, but 6 months of that has started showing damage. I need a software solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try going to Control Panel>Hardware and Sound and then clicking on Sound. Plug the headphones in and see if they show up. Also, have you updated your drivers recently?

Comment: My drivers are all updated to their newest versions, and as I said in my question, the headphones always show up as plugged in when they are. My problem is, when I start my computer with headphones plugged in, no sound is produced at all, until I unplug the headphones. Then they work fine if I plug them back in.

Comment: Very bizarre. It might be a hardware issue, but software-wise the only other thing I can think to do would be to make sure you don't have HD Audio Device installed as well. This can cause conflict with RHDAM, so if it's there remove it. Otherwise I hope you find a solution!